# WebStorm/JetBrains IDEs: Hotkey or Shortcut to expand split file panes?

Tags: webstorm, workflow, jetbrains-ide

I would like to know if there exists some functionality, hotkey, or shortcut in WebStorm (or any JetBrains IDE) that allows me to expand/minimize file split panes/sections easily. To illustrate what I mean, take this image to represent my current pane splits. Each color is a different file tab grouping. [image]

My goal is to be able to change the sizes of the splits like in the following two examples: [image]

[image]

Currently, in order to achieve this, I would have to manually use my mouse cursor to drag the pane splits. The closest functionality is exactly what I'm looking for is in Premiere Pro (Adobe), the default hotkey '`' allows you to maximize the currently hovered "frame" to take up the whole window. I essentially want that exact behaviour, so that I can quickly change between my "focused" split, while having the others still open, but out of the way.

`CMD+SHIFT+F12` is something I've seen everywhere, but that only removes all "tool windows" and maximizes the *editor pane* (the whole editor), and not the currently selected pane split section.

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that automatically resizes splits based on the selected split: [Golden Ratio](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19376-goldenratio). Turning the ratio closer to 1 makes it take up more space.